# symfony file update in production

Tags: symfony, production-environment

My symfony website works fine in production. But I change on of my file which is under the following adress:
/src/site/BlogBundle/Resources/view/blog/myfile.html.twig

But the change I made are unvisible online...
do I have to make extra change? clear a cache or something?

Answer (score 2):

If you only changed a HTML part, you can run

```
app/console --env=prod cache:clear
```

If you modified some of the JS or CSS, or you have modified one of the assetic blocks, you must also regenerate your assets:

```
app/console --env=prod assets:install
app/console --env=prod assetic:dump --force
```

Doesn’t hurt to run all three commands, although your site will be “broken” for about a minute before it is back to normal.

Comment: Yes I have only changed a html part. But do not want to retransfert everything throught filezilla. which part should I delete so that the cache is being deleted?

Comment: Don’t you have command line access? It’s not sufficient to delete old files; in `prod` mode, you also have to generate the new files (using above commands), as they are not being generated on the fly.

Comment: Yes Indeed I do not have command line access INLINE. so could you confirm the following: I should do "app/console --env=prod cache:clear" offline and then update the "bundles" file (/src/www/bundles) inline ?

Comment: Simply run the three commands on the CLI of your live server. This will update everything. If you run it offline, you'd have to deploy the re-generated files again.

Comment: ok which are the re-generated files (are they in the "Bundles" file). So far I do not have any CLI of my live server

Comment: Then you should create a new build on your dev machine and upload it to your live machine; at least the `app/` and the `web/` dirs.

Answer (score 0):

You must clear the cache in production environment :

```
 $ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```